# Need to set a variable based on the value of the selected item in a dropdown

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set a variable to the value of the selected item in a dropdown but can't get it to work properly. Here is the html:

```
<select id="locationChoice" name="WorkflowList">
<option value=" ">-- Please Select --</option>
<option value="14643">Item A</option>
<option value="14644">Item B</option>
<option value="14645">Item C</option>
</select>
```

Here's the jquery:

```
    var rfiSchooldropdown = $('#locationChoice:selected').val(); 
$("#locationChoice").change(function() {
alert(rfiSchooldropdown);
});
```

I know I'm close but it's not grabbing the value properly. I'm using "alert" to test, FYI.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set it again on the `change` event, like this:

```
var rfiSchooldropdown = $('#locationChoice').val(); //no :selected here
$("#locationChoice").change(function() {
  rfiSchooldropdown = $(this).val();     
  alert(rfiSchooldropdown);
});
```

Or, a bit simpler overall:

```
var rfiSchooldropdown;
$("#locationChoice").change(function() {
  rfiSchooldropdown = $(this).val();
  //use rfiSchooldropdown
}).change();
```

Note in the first example I removed [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/), [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) can be called directly on the `<select>` element itself.